# Spark installation conflicting with log4j

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, log4j

I'm building out a batch engine that runs different batch processes. For some of these processes, I do not need to use Spark. For this I am using a shaded plugin to build an "uber" jar with all of the dependencies within my jar.

When i have to run one of the processes that DOES NEED Spark, I run a spark submit command. But the Log4j within the jar is conflicting with the Spark installation on my server. How do I fix this?

```
SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION is set to 2, using Spark2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory loaded from file:/usr/hdp/2.6.5.1217-7/spark2/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml: org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory
```

Answer (score 0):

Split project on two subprojects - one with code for Spark, other for other purposes.

Comment: Yes, this has been a suggestion from another colleague. This may be my course of action. Another thing I was suggesting is, leveraging the log4j jar that is on the server for ALL the processes. To do this I would have to exclude the log4j dependency from the uber-jar so that it's not part of the jar file. Then reference the jar file on the server from the command line when I call my uber jar. Thoughts?

Comment: From exception message, looks like this can be fixed by removing "Logback" from classpath. If "slf4j" over "log4j" is used in project, maybe, "Logback" dependency can be removed, as suggested in message.